# Toggle overlay in a Primefaces GoogleMap

Tags: google-maps, jsf, primefaces, google-maps-markers

I am using Primefaces gmap to show markers and circle overlays on some markers. I want to toggle the circle overlay on a button click. Any idea how I can do that? I am using JSF 2.2 and Primefaces 3.4.2.

This is how I load the map in the jsf page.

```
<p:gmap center="21, 78" id="map" 
zoom="2" 
type="roadmap"
style="width:99%;height:90%;position:absolute"
model="#{SCNBean.supplyChainMapModel}"
widgetVar="mapVar">
```

This is how I load the markers and circle overlays in my backing bean.

```
@PostConstruct
public void viewSupplyChainNetwork(){
    for (Node node : supplyChainNodes) {
        LatLng coord = new LatLng(node.getLatitude(), node.getLongitude());
        marker = new Marker(coord, node.getAddress(), node, getMarkerIcon(node.getNodeType()));
        supplyChainMapModel.addOverlay(marker);
        //adding circle overlay
        Circle circle1 = new Circle(coord, riskval*10000);  
        circle1.setStrokeColor("#d93c3c");  
        circle1.setFillColor("#d93c3c");  
        circle1.setFillOpacity(0.7);
        supplyChainMapModel.addOverlay(circle1);
    }
```

Here is how the button on the map is created using javascript

```
function HeatMapControl(heatMapControlDiv, gmap) {
    heatMapControlDiv.style.padding = '5px';                                        
    var controlUI = document.createElement('div');
    controlUI.title = 'Heat Map';
    heatMapControlDiv.appendChild(controlUI);
    var controlText = document.createElement('div');
    controlText.innerHTML = '<strong>Heat Map</strong>';
    controlUI.appendChild(controlText);
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(controlUI, 'click', function() {
                                        heatmap.setMap(heatmap.getMap() ? null : gmap);
                                    });
```

I want to make the circle overlay toggle on the click of a button on the map. How can I achieve this?

Comment: since you obviously can't add buttons in a p:gmap, what do you mean by "click of a button on the map" ? Maybe you meant some click event like onOverlaySelect? Or a commandButton outside the gmap, that will toggle on/off all the circle Overlays ?  Also, what's the scope of your backing Bean

Comment: I've added a button using javascript. The bean is view scoped.

Comment: source code for the button? have you managed to catch the button action in the backing bean ?  Also have in mind that a ViewScoped Bean is not suitable for a p:gmap that will udpate it's mapModel. consider providint MapModel from a requestScoped bean

Comment: I've added the source code for the button to the original query. If I manage to get the click event in the bean, is it possible to make the overlay appear and disappear without recreating the map every time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would move the mapModel to a requestScoped Bean, let's call it SomeRequestScopedMapBean

it should have a reference to your current bean as a ManagedProperty

Your xhtml could work like this: (I don't think there is any need to create it with javascript, but I dit it with a commandButton)

```
    <p:gmap
    model="#{someRequestScopedMapBean.supplyChainMapModel}"
    widgetVar="mapVar"
    id="pgmapId">

<p:commandButton value="Toggle Circles"
    actionListener="#{sCNBean.toggleShowCircles}"
    ajax="true"
    update="pgmapId"
    />
```

Here's the callback for your action, in your viewScoped Backing bean

```
    public void toggleShowCircles(){
    if(showCircles)
        showCircles = false;
    else 
        showCircles = true;
}
```

The MapModel construction is moved to your SomeRequestScopedMapBean

```
@PostConstruct
public void drawMapModel(){
for (Node node : sCNBean.supplyChainNodes) {
    LatLng coord = new LatLng(node.getLatitude(), node.getLongitude());
    marker = new Marker(coord, node.getAddress(), node, getMarkerIcon(node.getNodeType()));
    supplyChainMapModel.addOverlay(marker);

    if(sCNBean.showCircles){
        //adding circle overlay
        Circle circle1 = new Circle(coord, riskval*10000);  
        circle1.setStrokeColor("#d93c3c");  
        circle1.setFillColor("#d93c3c");  
        circle1.setFillOpacity(0.7);
        supplyChainMapModel.addOverlay(circle1);
    }
}
```

Comment: But then I have to recreate the map every time which will be expensive, as I have to hit the database read the nodes and other details required to reconstruct the map on every toggle. I guess I will have to take this approach if there is no better way, but is there a way to avoid this? I see solutions in javascript, but I couldnt fit that because of the way I am constructing the overlays through backing bean.

Comment: no need to hit the database each time. The you do this once in the ViewScoped Bean which creates and provides the supplyChainNodes. the requestScoped Bean just draws the markers each time you draw the p:gmap.

Comment: That is nice. Thank you.